# Sub query en FROM con eloquent laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Como pudiera realizar este query utilizando eloquent y laravel?

```
SELECT 
    `product_id`, `sum(total)`
FROM (
    SELECT 
        `product_id`, `count(*) total`
    FROM `product_category`
    WHERE `category_id` IN ('223', '15')
    GROUP BY `product_id`
    union all
    SELECT 
        `product_id`, `count(*) total` 
    FROM `product_category`
    GROUP BY `product_id`
    WHERE `category_id` IN ('223', '15')
)
GROUP BY `product_id`
```

Answer (score 1):

La conversion es algo como:

```
$table = DB::table("product_category")
->select("product_id", "count (*) total")
->whereIn("category_id", ['223', '15'])
->groupBy("product_id");

DB::table("where_subquery_group_2_ total")
->select("product_id", "sum (total)")
->where(DB::raw("product_category"))

->union($table)->groupBy("product_id")
->get();
```

Comment: Muy bien, seria bueno si documentaras un poco el codigo